# Can we integrate spring-security directly with adal4j(Azure AD Authentication) in Java spring cloud through webportal?

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-cloud, azure-active-directory

I'm using below code in my `controller`. I'm using spring cloud and below is my code in web-portals controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
            @ResponseBody
            public void auth(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
                LOG.info("In loop1");
                String urlCurrent = request.getRequestURL().toString();
                URL url = new URL(urlCurrent);
                String urlString = AUTHORISATION_URL + "?response_type=code&client_id=" + CLIENT_ID + "&redirect_uri="
                        + REDIRECT_URL;
                String query = url.getQuery();
                String code = request.getParameter("code");
                String sessionState = request.getParameter("session_state");
                LOG.info("Values :: query::" + query + " code " + code + "=" + code + " sessionState::" + sessionState);
                if (code == null) {
                    response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(urlString));
                } else if (code != null && sessionState != null) {
                    LOG.info("session ID in method 1: " + request.getSession().getId());
                    urlRedirectionAfterAuthentication(code, request, response);
                } else {
                    response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(urlString));
                }
            }

            @ResponseBody
            public void urlRedirectionAfterAuthentication(String code, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws Exception {
                LOG.info("In Redirection Method");
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("authorisationCode", code);
                ADUser aduser = getAccessTokenAndUserInfo(request);
                LOG.info("session ID in method 2: " + request.getSession().getId());
                response.sendRedirect(REDIRECT_URL + "/index.html?lastName=" + aduser.getLastName() + "&firstName="
                        + aduser.getFirstName() + "&emailId=" + aduser.getEmailId());

                //AsymmetricKeyCredential credential = 

            }

            @RequestMapping(value = "getAccessTokenAndUserInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public ADUser getAccessTokenAndUserInfo(HttpServletRequest request) {
                LOG.info("Get Access Token");
                ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
                AuthenticationContext context = null;
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                LOG.info("session ID in method 3: " + request.getSession().getId());
                // String code = session.getAttribute("authorisationCode").toString();
                ADUser adUser = new ADUser();
                try {
                    context = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, false, service);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    LOG.error("Malformed URL: ", e);
                }
                ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
                Future<AuthenticationResult> authResultFuture = null;
                try {
        /*          authResultFuture = context.acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                            session.getAttribute("authorisationCode").toString(), new URI(REDIRECT_URL), credential, RESOURCE,
                            null);*/
                    authResultFuture = context.acquireToken(
                            new URI(REDIRECT_URL), credential, RESOURCE,
                            null);
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    LOG.error("URISyntaxException: ", e);
                }
                String userEmail = null;
                try {
                    LOG.info("Access token: " + authResultFuture.get().getAccessToken());
                    LOG.info("Expiry Time: " + authResultFuture.get().getExpiresAfter());
                    LOG.info("Refresh Time: " + authResultFuture.get().getRefreshToken());
                    LOG.info("User Info Display ID: " + authResultFuture.get().getUserInfo().getDisplayableId());
                    LOG.info("User Info Family ID: " + authResultFuture.get().getUserInfo().getFamilyName());
                    LOG.info("User Info Given Name: " + authResultFuture.get().getUserInfo().getGivenName());
                    LOG.info("Getting user info");
                    userEmail = authResultFuture.get().getUserInfo().getDisplayableId();

                    LOG.info("User email: " + userEmail);
                    adUser.setAccessToken(authResultFuture.get().getAccessToken());
                    adUser.setAuthorisationCode(session.getAttribute("authorisationCode").toString());
                    adUser.setEmailId(authResultFuture.get().getUserInfo().getDisplayableId());
                    adUser.setFirstName(authResultFuture.get().getUserInfo().getGivenName());
                    adUser.setLastName(authResultFuture.get().getUserInfo().getFamilyName());
                    adUser.setRefreshToken(authResultFuture.get().getRefreshToken());
                    adUser.setTimeToLive(String.valueOf(authResultFuture.get().getExpiresAfter()));
                    return adUser;
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    LOG.error("ExecutionException: ", e);
                    return null;
                }
            }

        In the method urlRedirection, if i do not use index.html, the loop is infinite:
        response.sendRedirect(REDIRECT_URL + "/index.html?lastName=" + aduser.getLastName() + "&firstName="
                    + aduser.getFirstName() + "&emailId=" + aduser.getEmailId()
```

But when I login to app with /index.html AD lets me in without Authentication. I'm using below dependency in maven:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

ADAL is a library that helps you get tokens for calling web services.  That's it.  It won't actually help you sign users into a web app (i.e. establishing a session), secure your web app, or protect a web service.

At this point in time the best advice I can offer you is to find an open source OpenID Connect or OAuth spring library/middleware and use that to connect to Azure AD.